# Loop through html with beautifulsoup grabbing two elements from each <hr> tag then move on to the next and do the same

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Original question here: [Scrape Certain elements from HTML using Python and Beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74778403/scrape-certain-elements-from-html-using-python-and-beautifulsoup/74778465#74778465)

Follow-up question:

How do I loop through the entire html page grabbing the same info from each `<hr>`?

The raw data would look like this:

```
<hr>
<b>1946 December 13 - </b>. 
<i>Launch Site</i>: <a href="http://www.astronautix.com/w/whitesands.html">White Sands</a>. 
<i>Launch Complex</i>: <a href="http://www.astronautix.com/w/whitesandslc33.html">White Sands LC33</a>. 
<i>LV Family</i>: <a href="http://www.astronautix.com/w/wac.html">WAC</a>. 
<i>Launch Vehicle</i>: <a href="http://www.astronautix.com/w/wacb.html">WAC B</a>. 
<ul><li><b>Test mission</b> - . 
<i>Nation</i>: <a href="http://www.astronautix.com/u/usa.html">USA</a>. 
<i>Agency</i>: <a href="http://www.astronautix.com/u/usaor.html">USA OR</a>. 
<i>Apogee</i>: 53 km (32 mi). </li></ul>

<hr>
<b>1948 December 13 - </b>. 
<ul><li><b>XS-1 Flight 102</b> - . 
<i>Crew</i>: <a href="http://www.astronautix.com/y/yeager.html">Yeager</a>. 
 <i>Payload</i>: XS-1 # 1 flight 59. <i>Nation</i>: <a href="http://www.astronautix.com/u/usa.html">USA</a>. 
<i>Related Persons</i>: <a href="http://www.astronautix.com/y/yeager.html">Yeager</a>. 
<i>Class</i>: <a href="http://www.astronautix.com/m/manned.html">Manned</a>. 
 <i>Type</i>: Manned rocketplane. <i>Spacecraft</i>: <a href="http://www.astronautix.com/x/xs-1.html">XS-1</a>. 
AF flight 37. Handling qualities and wing and tail loads at mach 1.. 
</li></ul>

<hr>
<b>1953 December 13 - </b>. 
<i>Launch Vehicle</i>: <a href="http://www.astronautix.com/r/r-11.html">R-11</a>. 
<ul><li><b>R-11 production decree</b> - . 
<i>Nation</i>: <a href="http://www.astronautix.com/r/russia.html">Russia</a>. 
<p>A government decree was issued for SKB-385 in the Urals to be 
responsible for series production of the R-11 and its S2.253 engine. 
SKB-385 had not distinguished itself in 1949-1951 when it was 
responsible for the first abortive attempt to put the R-1 rocket into 
production.</p></li></ul>

<hr>
<b>1954 December 13 - </b>. 
<i>LV Family</i>: <a href="http://www.astronautix.com/a/atlas.html">Atlas</a>. 
<i>Launch Vehicle</i>: <a href="http://www.astronautix.com/a/atlas.html">Atlas</a>. 
<ul><li><b>First production funding for Atlas.</b> - . 
Air Force Procurement Authorization 54-GM-3 authorized $3.6 million in 
P-150 production funding for Atlas. This was the first production 
funding for Atlas.. 
</li></ul>

<hr>
<b>1955 December 13 - </b>. 
05:00 GMT - . 
<i>Launch Site</i>: <a href="http://www.astronautix.com/w/whitesands.html">White Sands</a>. 
<i>Launch Complex</i>: <a href="http://www.astronautix.com/w/whitesandslc35.html">White Sands LC35</a>. 
<i>LV Family</i>: <a href="http://www.astronautix.com/a/aerobee.html">Aerobee</a>. 
<i>Launch Vehicle</i>: <a href="http://www.astronautix.com/a/aerobeertv-n-10a.html">Aerobee RTV-N-10a</a>. 
<ul><li><b>Airglow / Mass spectrometer Aeronomy mission</b> - . 
<i>Nation</i>: <a href="http://www.astronautix.com/u/usa.html">USA</a>. 
<i>Agency</i>: <a href="http://www.astronautix.com/n/nrl.html">NRL</a>. 
<i>Apogee</i>: 142 km (88 mi). Gas composition research. Launched at 2200 local time. Reached 142 km.. 
</li></ul>

<hr>
<b>1955 December 13 - </b>. 
17:58 GMT - . 
<i>Launch Site</i>: <a href="http://www.astronautix.com/h/holloman.html">Holloman</a>. 
<i>Launch Complex</i>: <a href="http://www.astronautix.com/h/hollomana.html">Holloman A</a>. 
<i>LV Family</i>: <a href="http://www.astronautix.com/a/aerobee.html">Aerobee</a>. 
<i>Launch Vehicle</i>: <a href="http://www.astronautix.com/a/aerobeeaj10-27.html">Aerobee AJ10-27</a>. 
<ul><li><b>Colorado UVS Solar ultraviolet mission</b> - . 
<i>Nation</i>: <a href="http://www.astronautix.com/u/usa.html">USA</a>. 
<i>Agency</i>: <a href="http://www.astronautix.com/u/usaf.html">USAF</a>. 
<i>Apogee</i>: 138 km (85 mi). Lyman alpha, solar limb darkening research. Launched at 1058 local time. Reached 138.4 km.. 
</li></ul>
```

The provided info works on the first `<hr>` but then I can't get it to go to the next one. I have been able to get it to repeat the same info x times or get just the first tag.

My loop looks like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")


with open("test1.txt", "w") as file:
    hrs = soup.find_all('hr')
    for hr in hrs:
        title = soup.find("li").b.text
        text = soup.find("li").contents[-1].strip(" .\n")
        file.write("Today in #Space #History- "+title+" "+text.strip()+"\n")
```

This gives the output of:

```
Today in #Space #History- X-1 manned supersonic rocket aircraft begun. In an AAF-NACA conference, Air Force representatives indicated strong preference for use of rocket engines instead of jets in X-1 research airplane project..
Today in #Space #History- X-1 manned supersonic rocket aircraft begun. In an AAF-NACA conference, Air Force representatives indicated strong preference for use of rocket engines instead of jets in X-1 research airplane project..
Today in #Space #History- X-1 manned supersonic rocket aircraft begun. In an AAF-NACA conference, Air Force representatives indicated strong preference for use of rocket engines instead of jets in X-1 research airplane project..
Today in #Space #History- X-1 manned supersonic rocket aircraft begun. In an AAF-NACA conference, Air Force representatives indicated strong preference for use of rocket engines instead of jets in X-1 research airplane project..
Today in #Space #History- X-1 manned supersonic rocket aircraft begun. In an AAF-NACA conference, Air Force representatives indicated strong preference for use of rocket engines instead of jets in X-1 research airplane project..
Today in #Space #History- X-1 manned supersonic rocket aircraft begun. In an AAF-NACA conference, Air Force representatives indicated strong preference for use of rocket engines instead of jets in X-1 research airplane project..
```

I am getting from other threads that it's only grabbing the first element, but I can't figure out how to get it to keep going through the rest of the page.

It would also be nice to know why it is repeating, I feel like what's happening is that the for loop is grabbing the number of elements correctly but then the loop isn't updating the variables "title" and "text" so those are getting printed repeatedly the number of times the first element appears on the whole page.

I worked for a long time on this before I came back to make sure and do my due diligence but I am STUCK.

UPDATE:
I understand that there is obviously something wrong with the way I'm thinking about this for loop so I'll write what I think is going on if someone can help me correct my own thinking.

The page in question is horribly organized and changes each day so for today's page it would be like this:

```
http://www.astronautix.com/d/december14.html
```

Here's what I think the loop is doing:

```
for hr in hrs:
```

Find each `<hr>` element on the page, I picked that because the `<hr>` tag precedes every section of data that I want to target.

```
title = soup.find("li").b.text
text = soup.find("li").contents[-1].strip(" .\n")
```

Within each `<hr>` section, grab the contents of `<b>` and the `<li>` and store them in variables.

Then what I think should happen is that it should iterate down to the next `<hr>` and do the same but my logic is very obviously flawed.

Comment: I think afterwards I could modify with if statements to select elements if they exist, but getting this loop going is killing me lol.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I loop through the entire html page grabbing the same info ***from*** each `<hr>`?

Actually, `hr` tag is for displaying a horizontal line across a page (like you might see below this, and probably several more times in my answer), so there isn't anything *in* it that you can get *from* it.

---

What you seem to want is the some content that comes from the `li` tag *after* each `<hr>`.

> It would also be nice to know why it is repeating

That's because you're doing the same thing every loop - `soup` was defined outside the loop, and it's not changed again, and it refers to the whole document, so ofc `soup.find("li")...` is not a thing that will differ in the next loop.

The thing that changes is **`hr`** [from `for hr in hrs`], so that's what you need to use for new content. However, there is no use applying `.find(...)` to `hr` since, like I explained, there's nothing *in* it; but you *can* use [`.find_next(...)`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) instead:

```py
    for hr in soup.find_all('hr'):
        title = hr.find_next("li").b.text
        text = hr.find_next("li").contents[-1].strip(" .\n")
```

---

But it's rather redundant to call `.find_next("li")` twice; and also, if there are two `hr` tags with no `li` tags between them, then the `li` from before the first (of those 2 `hr`s) will be repeated. So, it's better to first get the next-`li` tags and then get [eliminate repetition](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/set) before extracting `title` and `text`.

```py
    liList = [li for li in set([
        hr.find_next("li") for hr in soup.select('hr')
    ]) if li.b] # remove risk of error when getting title
    for li in liList:
        title = li.b.text
        text = li.contents[-1].strip(" .\n")
```

(You can use [`.select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) with [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php) like `liList = soup.select('hr ~ * li:has(b)')`, but that will have another issue - if there are multiple `li` tags between two `hr` tags. [But if you *want* all of the `li` tags, not just one after each `hr`, then this is useful.])

---

Now, the possibility of error at `title = li.b.text` if an `li` does not have any `b` tags has been avoided, but there is still an issue with *`li.contents[-1].strip(" .\n")`* - it assumes that the last content of the li tag will be a string, but even in your sample HTML snippet, after the 3r `hr`, the `li` ends with a `p` tag, so you will get an error there. You can get the last string content of every `li` with

```py
        text = [t for t in li.contents if isinstance(t, str)]
        text = (text[-1] if text else '').strip(" .")
```

or you can get the text from the last content [full code this time]

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

with open("test1.txt", "w") as file:
    liList = [li for li in set([
        hr.find_next("li") for hr in soup.select('hr')
    ]) if li.b] # remove risk of error when getting title
    for li in liList:
        title = li.b.text
        text = [getattr(
            c, 'text', c if isinstance(c, str) else ''
        ) for c in li.contents]
        text = (text[-1] if text else '').strip(" .")
        file.write("Today in #Space #History- "+title+" "+text.strip()+"\n")
```

Comment: My goodness. Thank you so much for correcting my thinking here. It was an aha moment, I'd totally donate to your patreon.

Comment: @qLu now I wish I had a patreon haha...glad it helped!